# Updating Access Database from vb.net DataGridView

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

So basically, the problem I am having is that I change values fine and when clicking the amend button is gives no errors and updates the shown DataGridView fine. However it is not actually updating the Access database. Meaning if the program is closed or whatever and reopened the values go back to the original ones the program gets from the database. Clearly showing it is not being updated.

```
    Dim dsConnectionM As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dsConnectionL As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dsConnectionE As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dsDataAdapterM As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dsDataAdapterL As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dsDataAdapterE As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dsDataSetM As DataSet
    Dim dsDataSetL As DataSet
    Dim dsDataSetE As DataSet

    Public Sub dsLoadMembers()
        dsConnectionM = New OleDbConnection
        dsConnectionM.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=DataSourceDB.accdb"
        dsDataAdapterM = New OleDbDataAdapter
        dsDataAdapterM.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand
        dsDataAdapterM.SelectCommand.Connection = dsConnectionM
        dsDataAdapterM.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Member"
        dsDataAdapterM.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        dsConnectionM.Open()
        dsDataSetM = New DataSet
        dsDataAdapterM.Fill(dsDataSetM, "dataSetMembers")
        dsConnectionM.Close()
        Form3.dgdMembers.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        Form3.dgdMembers.DataSource = dsDataSetM
        Form3.dgdMembers.DataMember = "dataSetMembers"
    End Sub

    Public Sub AmendMember()
        Form3.dgdMembers.Rows(Form3.m).Cells("MemberID").Value = Form3.tbid.Text
        Form3.dgdMembers.Rows(Form3.m).Cells("Forename").Value = Form3.tbfn.Text
        Form3.dgdMembers.Rows(Form3.m).Cells("Surname").Value = Form3.tbsn.Text
        Form3.dgdMembers.Rows(Form3.m).Cells("DOB").Value = Form3.dtpdob.Value
        Form3.dgdMembers.Rows(Form3.m).Cells("Section").Value = Form3.tbsr.Text
        Form3.dgdMembers.Rows(Form3.m).Cells("Postcode").Value = Form3.tbpc.Text
        Form3.dgdMembers.Rows(Form3.m).Cells("HomeTel").Value = Form3.tbht.Text
        Form3.dgdMembers.Rows(Form3.m).Cells("MobileTel").Value = Form3.tbmt.Text
        Form3.dgdMembers.Rows(Form3.m).Cells("AddressLine1").Value = Form3.tbal1.Text
        Form3.dgdMembers.Rows(Form3.m).Cells("AddressLine2").Value = Form3.tbal2.Text
        Form3.dgdMembers.Rows(Form3.m).Cells("City").Value = Form3.tbc.Text
        Form3.dgdMembers.Rows(Form3.m).Cells("EmailAddress").Value = Form3.tbea.Text
        Form3.dgdMembers.Rows(Form3.m).Cells("P/GForename").Value = Form3.tbpgfn.Text
        Form3.dgdMembers.Rows(Form3.m).Cells("P/GSurname").Value = Form3.tbpgsn.Text
        dsConnectionM.Open()
        dsDataAdapterM.Update(dsDataSetM, "dataSetMembers")
        dsDataSetM.AcceptChanges()
        dsConnectionM.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: You are writing the data to the grid, but not moving the data from the grid to the dataset. Also, it's not necessary to call AcceptChanges on the dataset - this happens automatically as part of the update. Personally, rather than write all that cod, I'd bind the grid to the dataset via a BindingSource. Then I would update the dataset, and then refresh the grid.

Comment: So how do I update the dataset using my way? Since I already have so much code written using similar code for several tables and my coursework deadline is coming up.

Comment: Given that by trying to do it this way round, you are fighting the way it's supposed to be used, I'm not sure that submitting this as coursework is of any value. I'd recommend you have a look at the [BindingSource component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxxf124e(v=vs.110).aspx) Use its EndEdit method to move the data from the textboxes to the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check that your data source is the full path of the database.
Also, there is any easier way to update a database; you can use an UPDATE statement to do it.
In my public class I have the following declared:

```
Dim provider As String
Dim datafile As String
Dim connString As String
Dim myconnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
```

Now for the actual example of code:

```
myconnection.open()
dim variable as string
variable = "UPDATE tablename SET columnname = value WHERE (enter criteria )"
Dim cmd as oledbcommand = New oledbcommand(variable, myconnection)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
myconnection.close()
```

So for your code:

```
Public Sub AmendMember()
    myconnection.open()
    variable = "UPDATE dataSetMembers SET MemberID = '" & Form3.tbid.text &"', Forename = '" & Form3.tbfn.Text &"', Surname = '" & Form3.tbsn.Text &"', DOB = '" & Form3.dtpdob.text &"', Section = '" & Form3.tbsr.Text &"', Postcode = '" & Form3.tbpc.Text &"', HomeTel = '" & Form3.tbht.Text &"', MobileTel = '" & Form3.tbmt.Text &"', AddressLine1 = '" & Form3.tbal1.Text &"', AddressLine2 = '" & Form3.tbal2.Text &"', City = '" & Form3.tbc.Text &"', EmailAddress = '" & Form3.tbea.Text &"', P/GForename = '" & Form3.tbpgfn.Text &"', P/GSurname = '" & Form3.tbpgsn.Text &" "
    Dim cmd as oledbcommand = New oledbcommand(variable, myconnection)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myconnection.close()
End Sub
```

In this I have assumed the name of your table from your previous code.

Comment: I tried the code you provided and it throws an error when the button is clicked.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

Comment: @ItsSimplyEddie I'd advise try getting rid of the brackets in the UPDATE statement and see if that works. It could be as simple as that. If it doesn't, then check how you've declared the database path. I will edit this in my answer.

Comment: Hi, I tried changing it as you said and also tried as the following:

Comment: memberUpdate = "UPDATE Member SET MemberID = '" & Form3.tbid.Text & "', Forename = '" & Form3.tbfn.Text & "', Surname = '" & Form3.tbsn.Text & "', DOB = '" & Form3.dtpdob.Value & "', Section = '" & Form3.tbsr.Text & "', Postcode = '" & Form3.tbpc.Text & "', HomeTel = '" & Form3.tbht.Text & "', MobileTel = '" & Form3.tbmt.Text & "', AddressLine1 = '" & Form3.tbal1.Text & "', AddressLine2 = '" & Form3.tbal2.Text & "', City = '" & Form3.tbc.Text & "', EmailAddress = '" & Form3.tbea.Text & "', P/GForename = '" & Form3.tbpgfn.Text & "', P/GSurname = '" & Form3.tbpgsn.Text & "'"

Comment: @ItsSimplyEddie I need more info on what your error message is. And also, make sure the right database things are declared at the start. Also, I dont understand why your code looks like it has many different database connections and adapters. It should be one database that you're using. Tag me when you respond so I get a notification.

Comment: I told you the error. 

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

Comment: @ItsSimplyEddie Try putting [ ] around the column names. It could be that the program is confusing the variables. E.g. memberUpdate = "UPDATE Member SET [MemberID] = '" & Form3.tbid.Text & "', [Forename] = '" & Form3.tbfn.Text & "', [Surname] = '" & Form3.tbsn.Text & "' + etc. Also, do you not have a criteria you want set for this? As in an update to set something WHERE something else. I want to make sure that Member is the name of the table in the database and that all the column headings have the same capitalisation as in the database.